# /lib is not writable even for root

Tags: filesystem

What can cause `/lib` not being accessible even for `root`?

I can't install new packages because almost every package wants to write to `/lib`.

Someone suggested antivirus, but I have none. The only thing I remember installing is `LXD`.

```
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
```

```
# mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=32925888k,nr_inodes=8231472,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=6596552k,mode=755)
/dev/md2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset,clone_children)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=24,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=27100)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/dev/md1 on /boot type ext3 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
lxcfs on /var/lib/lxcfs type fuse.lxcfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
tmpfs on /var/lib/lxd/shmounts type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=100k,mode=711)
tmpfs on /var/lib/lxd/devlxd type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=100k,mode=755)
/var/lib/lxd/disks/default.img on /var/lib/lxd/storage-pools/default type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache,user_subvol_rm_allowed,subvolid=5,subvol=/)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing type tracefs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=6596548k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=6596548k,mode=700)
```

```
# stat /lib
  File: /lib
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 902h/2306d      Inode: 5767169     Links: 17
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-03-30 09:34:07.260619267 +0200
Modify: 2019-05-30 17:56:34.581935968 +0200
Change: 2019-05-30 17:56:37.801900596 +0200
 Birth: -
# ls -ld /lib
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4096 May 30  2019 /lib/
```

Comment: On my Ubuntu 19.10 /lib is a symbolic link to usr/lib, and based on your "stat /lib" command yours isn't. Verify with "ls -la /lib"

Comment: Correction: I didn't see that you've included "ls -ld /lib", thats sufficient. Yours is not symlinked.

Comment: Can you provide an example showing root failing to write to `/lib`? FWIW it's a regular directory not a symlink on my 18.04 system